# Best way to format single & double values as strings for SimpleDB?

Tags: c#, amazon-simpledb

Amazon's SimpleDB stores values as strings, and I need to store numeric values so that they still compare correctly, for example:

"0001" < "0002"

I think bytes, integers and decimals will be fairly straightforward, but I'm a little unsure on the best way to handle singles and doubles, since they can be very small or large and would appreciate any suggestions from those more clever than I!

(I'm using C#)

Comment: Can we have information for those of us not familiar with Amazon's SimpleDB?

Comment: This is probably the best starting point: http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a way to represent sign-magnitude numbers (like the `integers` that you said wouldn't be too hard), then you're already there ;-]

From [Comparing Floating Point Numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)

> **The IEEE float and double formats were
>   designed so that the numbers are
>   “lexicographically ordered”**, which –
>   in the words of IEEE architect William
>   Kahan means “if two floating-point
>   numbers in the same format are ordered
>   ( say x < y ), then **they are ordered
>   the same way when their bits are
>   reinterpreted as Sign-Magnitude
>   integers.”**

```
static public string DoubleToSortableString(double dbl)
{
    Int64 interpretAsLong =
        BitConverter.ToInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(dbl), 0);
    return LongToSortableString(interpretAsLong);
}

static public double DoubleFromSortableString(string str)
{
    Int64 interpretAsLong =
        LongFromSortableString(str);
    return BitConverter.ToDouble(BitConverter.GetBytes(interpretAsLong), 0);
}

static public string LongToSortableString(long lng)
{
    if (lng < 0)
        return "-" + (~lng).ToString("X16");
    else
        return "0" + lng.ToString("X16");
}

static public long LongFromSortableString(string str)
{
    if (str.StartsWith("-"))
        return ~long.Parse(str.Substring(1, 16), NumberStyles.HexNumber); 
    else
        return long.Parse(str.Substring(1, 16), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

```
-0010000000000000 => -1.79769313486232E+308
-3F0795FFFFFFFFFF => -100000
-3F3C77FFFFFFFFFF => -10000
-3F70BFFFFFFFFFFF => -1000
-3FA6FFFFFFFFFFFF => -100
-3FDBFFFFFFFFFFFF => -10
-400FFFFFFFFFFFFF => -1
00000000000000000 => 0
03FF0000000000000 => 1
04024000000000000 => 10
04059000000000000 => 100
0408F400000000000 => 1000
040C3880000000000 => 10000
040F86A0000000000 => 100000
07FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF => 1.79769313486232E+308
```

Comment: Also, singles won't be comparable to doubles, and neither will be comparable to ints with this scheme.

Comment: Yikes!  Was that a requirement (mixed types)?  I suppose he could just use everything as doubles (like you suggested)...

Comment: @Daniel L -- No, the problem is signed-magnitude integers don't compare lexically for negative values (unless you're using signed-magnitude hardware, but who has that these days?).  He'll need to go to 2's complement or some other offset system rather than signed magnitude.

Comment: @Markus: Yeah, I know; I already punted that part to him, since he said he knew how to do that.

Comment: Thanks so much, this really points me in the right direction.  And, I think I might as well use a variation of this method for storing the other numerics.  Btw, I won't need to mix types, so fortunately I can avoid all that mess.

Answer (score 0):

One option (if you don't require they be human-readable) would be to store the exponent first (zero-filled), then the mantissa.  Something like "(07:4.5) for what would normally be written 4.5e7.

`*`smile`*`  Are you going to be dealing with signed values or positive floats less than 1?  If so, you'll need to do something like [offsets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/2007-11-07/DeveloperGuide/) as well, but on your brackets (e.g. [] for positive, () for negative) as well as the mantissa.

If you want to be able to sort integers in with your singles, etc.  You should probably just normalize everything to the largest type (e.g. your doubles) on the way in rather than trying to get too tricky.

Thus:

- 7   --> [100,17.0]
- 0.1 --> [099,11.0]
- -2  --> (100,08.0)

and so on.

Comment: Great ideas, thanks!  Signed values, yes, but mixed types, no.  Each "column" (attribute) in the SimpleDB will be of a single type.